# MIPS Assembly, setting array[index - i] = IntReturnFunction(argument)

Tags: c++, assembly, mips

I am new to using the stack and functions in MIPS, for an assignment we are translating a c++ program into MIPS in order to learn how functions work. My problem is translating this c++ code into MIPS, `intArr[valsToDo - i] = GetOneIntByVal(entIntPrompt);`.

I will show what I have so far but keep getting `address out of range` error.

```
#            intArr[valsToDo - i] = GetOneIntByVal(entIntPrompt);

                addi $a0, $sp, 41
                jal GetOneIntByVal
                sw $v0, 41($sp)
                lw $a1, 77($sp)
                sub $a3, $t1, $t1   #$a3 has valsToDo - i
                sll $a3, $a3, 2     #$a3 has (valsToDo - i) * 4
                add $a3, $a3, $a1   #$a3 has &intArr[valsToDo - i]
                lw $a2, 0($a3)      #$a2 has intArr[valsToDo - i]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) `sub $a3, $t1, $t1` means `$a3 = 0`. 2) We have no idea of knowing from the code you've shown us what's at `77($sp)` (why is `$sp` unaligned btw?)

Comment: And of course, in a simulator like SPIM or MARS you can see the values of all the registers, which should make it easy for you to figure out which of them that are incorrect.